# How to debug Lazy<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-loading

I have a `Lazy<T>` initialized with a lambda. How to see the body of the initializing lambda while debugging? I expect to have something like the `DebugView` of the `Expression` class but I've found nothing like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Lazy<T>` takes a delegate, there is no `Expression` class involved. Your lambda is compiled like any other code in your project and there is no preview of that code during debug.

Lambda expression can be compiled either into IL or transformed into Expression Tree. Which one happens depends on the context. If your parameter is declared as delegate regular IL code will be generated. If it's `Expression<TFunc>` you'll get expression tree which can be previewed.

It's nicely [explained on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), based on `Where` method, which has two versions: `Enumerable.Where` which takes `Func<T, bool>` and `Queryable.Where` which takes `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

> When you use method-based syntax to call the Where method in the
>   `Enumerable` class (as you do in LINQ to Objects and LINQ to XML) the
>   parameter is a delegate type `System.Func<T, TResult>`. A lambda
>   expression is the most convenient way to create that delegate. When
>   you call the same method in, for example, the `System.Linq.Queryable`
>   class (as you do in LINQ to SQL) then the parameter type is an
>   `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func>` where `Func` is any of the `Func`
>   delegates with up to sixteen input parameters. Again, a lambda
>   expression is just a very concise way to construct that expression
>   tree. **The lambdas allow the `Where` calls to look similar although in
>   fact the type of object created from the lambda is different.**

Comment: So I have 3k Lazy<string> objects initialized with different lambdas. Some of them result in nulls. The lambdas contain LINQ expression and I can't put breakpoints to see what happens. Of course, I can rewrite them in a more "breakpoint-friendly" way but... I thought there must be a smarter solution.